# How do I create HornetQ durable subscribers in an MDB?

Tags: jboss, messaging

Using JBoss 6 how do I setup durable subscribers and configure MDB's?

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Are you using JBoss AS 6 or JBoss EAP 6?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "VerySimpleMDB", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "/jms/topic/targetTopic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI",propertyValue = "true"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientID", propertyValue = "quickuser"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = "topicBridge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "shareSubscriptions", propertyValue="true"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hA", propertyValue = "true")
},mappedName = "java:jboss/jms/topic/targetTopic")

public class VerySimpleMDB implements MessageListener {
```